# How to refactor this Ramda async pipe to be more succinct

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm new to programming with Ramda. I refactored an async function to the below point-free style, however, I feel I could clean it up and make it more succinct was I more familiar with Ramda utility functions.

```
    currentPercentage: R.pipeWith(R.andThen)([
      async sloId => ({ sloId, slo: await SLOs.read(sloId) }),
      async ({ sloId, slo }) => ({ slo, stream: await Streams.findBySLOId(sloId) }),
      async ({ slo, stream }) => ({ slo, events: await Streams.readEvents(stream.id) }),
      async ({ slo, events }) => currentPercentage(slo.denominator)(interpret(events)),
    ]),
```

What are your recommendations for further using Ramda utilities to rewrite this code in an idiomatic functional style?

I'm looking to make it simpler to understand by reducing the number of variables you need to juggle mentally.

A pseudo-code example of what I have in mind (might be the wrong direction to refactor towards):

```
    currentPercentage: R.pipeWith(R.andThen)([
      wrap,
      merge("slo", SLOs.read),
      merge("stream" Streams.findBySLOId),
      merge("events", Streams.readEvents),
      async ({ slo, events }) => currentPercentage(slo.denominator)(interpret(events)),
    ]),
```

I have a hunch I should be using the functions `R.merge` and `R.pick`, but not sure how to use them usefully in this context. Or maybe there's another utility that'll do the job.

The answer may be this is as simple as it gets.

**update**

After some experimenting, was able to refactor my code to:

```
    currentPercentage: asyncPipe(loadSLOandResults(SLOs, Streams), currentPercentage),
```

```
const loadSLOandResults = (SLOs: SLOsAPI, Streams: StreamsAPI) =>
  asyncPipe(
    SLOs.read,
    async slo => ({ slo, stream: await Streams.findBySLOId(slo.id) }),
    async ({ slo, stream }) => ({ slo, results: interpret(await Streams.readEvents(stream.id)) })
  )
```

I changed the function signature of `currentPercentage` to line up with the return value of `loadSLOandResults`.

I created an `asyncPipe` utility function to make code slightly less verbose.

Comment: Tbh your refactoring introduced more points than a simple straightforward `async function` would have.

Comment: @Bergi I think it's expected when experimenting with new idioms to first get messier before becoming more orderly. After I posted this question, I was able to refactor it much cleaner than my initial code before using async pipes.